Handling Version Reverts in iOS Semantic Versioning and App Store Guidelines
I am new to semantic versioning and have a question regarding iOS releases and App Store guidelines.
According to Apple's technotes, new version numbers must be added in ascending sequential order as you create new releases.
We use a version naming format of Major.Minor.Patch.
Suppose I released a major feature (Version 2.5.0) that caused issues in production and needs to be reverted. Logically, I would need to decrement the major version to revert to the old state. For example, downgrading from 2.5.0 to 1.5.1 would make conceptual sense but is not supported by Apple's guidelines.
The same issue arises with minor version reverts.
Given this situation, how should I change the version number if major or minor features need to be reverted?

Your versions must always move up, so if you release 2.5.0 and it has issues then your next App Store version must be at least 2.5.1. This is nothing to do with what you do in Git with the actual source code. Typically you would have a release branch for each version, so if you needed to go back to 1.5.1 you would branch from the 1.5.1 release branch to a 2.5.1 release branch and release that.
